# Not number chapter but add to TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Change log}

\section{Section1}

\section{Section2}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I added `*` to `\section` to remove the section number. However, I would like this section to be included in TOC. How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\addcontentsline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section*{Change log}\label{sec:change}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:change}}
    
    \section{Section1}
    
    \section{Section2}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the line: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{change log}`

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{change log}
    \section*{Change log}
    \section{Section1}

\section{Section2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is an overleaf page tutorial where it is suggested: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/table_of_contents

Comment: As a general advice I would put `\addcontentsline` *after* `\section*`. The latter might trigger a new page.